# The number of abelian groups up to isomophism of order $6^5$

Tags: abelian-groups

The number of abelian groups up to isomophism of order $6^5$ is

$a)\ 5\\ b)\ 7\\ c)\ 49\\ d)\ 65$

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is $49$...$6^5=2^5 3^5$ and number of distinct partition of $5 =7$...so there are $7(7) =49$ number of abelian group up to isomorphism of order $6^5$.

Comment: You are correct. But do you understand why you can use partitions?

Answer (score 0):

well, it is $P(5)^2$.

We calculate $P(n)$ with the euclidean recurrence starting with $P_0$:

$1,1,2,3,5,7$.

So the answer is $7^2$

Comment: We don't really have to calculate anything. 49 is the only square number among the answer options, so...

Comment: thats sort of cheap imho

Comment: Yeah, sure, but it may help one through the exam.

Comment: Can you explain please how its P(5)^2?

Comment: by the fundamental theorem of abelian groups the group is a product of prime power cyclic subgroups,  so we can treat the powers of $2$ and $3$ seperately, for the powers of $2$ you need groups of size $2^a$ such that the sum of the exponents is $5$, there are $P(5)$ ways to do so, the same happens for the powers of $3$.